# Sitecore get data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, sitecore

I have created a form for users to fill in information and submit (Save Data). I can then export the data via CSV or email.

Is it possible to get this data via API?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might need `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IFormDataProvider.GetEntries(formId, start, end)` API.

The class lives in `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.dll` assembly.

Implementing instance can be fetched using [ServiceLocator, like in article](https://sitecorescientist.com/2018/11/02/sitecore-9-forms-part-1-basic-form-with-email-exist-validation/), or in a cleaner way using [Sitecore OOB DI + constructor injection](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/dependency-injection.html).

I'd like to warn the API gets slow as the number of forms grows - you might need to report that to Sitecore Support and get a support patch.